# Angular JS Controller Initialization Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just starting out with Angular.js controller and I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: app.controlller is not a function` when I try to initialize the angular controller.

Have a look at my snippet.

```js
var app = app;
if (!app) {
  app = angular.module('app', []);
  console.log("created app");
};
app.controlller('languages', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = 'None';
    $scope.js = function() {
      $scope.selected = 'JavaScript';
    };
    $scope.cpp = function() {
      $scope.cpp = 'C++';
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='languages'>
    Select a language:
    <button ng-click='js()'>JavaScript</button>
    <button ng-click='cpp()'>C++</button>
    <p>You have selected {{ selected }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There is one extra `l` in `app.controlller`. Should be `app.controller`.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out! But the cpp() function still doesn't work. Any reason?

Comment: oh got it. there's a typo there again

Answer (score 1):

There is TYPO error in controller

`app.controlller` this should be `app.controller`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! But the cpp() function still doesn't work. Any reason?

Comment: you have created same name for function and model

`$scope.cpp = function() {
      $scope.cpp = 'C++';
    };`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed typo `controlller` and changed `cpp()` function to set `$scope.selected = 'C++'`.

```js
var app = app;
if (!app) {
  app = angular.module('app', []);
  console.log("created app");
};
app.controller('languages', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = 'None';
    $scope.js = function() {
      $scope.selected = 'JavaScript';
    };
    $scope.cpp = function() {
      $scope.selected= 'C++';
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='languages'>
    Select a language:
    <button ng-click='js()'>JavaScript</button>
    <button ng-click='cpp()'>C++</button>
    <p>You have selected {{ selected }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just write a small snippet about what you have changed here to let other readers know.